# How to set Geofire in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, geofire

I'm a newbie in NodeJS as well in Geofire. So, I want to know wheter is possible to set Geofire in NodeJS or not. 
I've tried to do the following:
...

```
var geofire = require('geofire')
var firebase = require('firebase');
var db = new firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref('path/to/repo');
geofire = new Geofire(ref) ; // THIS DOESN'T WORK.
```

I couldn't set geofire object properly. How could I do it in the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to respect the case in your first line :

```
var GeoFire = require('geofire');
```

then

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
// Create a GeoFire index
var ref = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. For some reason I didn't notice the case. I was tired I guess. However, firebase ref is set in the way you do. That made it work as expected.Thanks.